# Changing modules without restarting Morbo (Mojolicious)

Tags: perl, module, mojolicious

I have got a Mojolicious::Lite app:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use User;

get '/' => sub {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->render('index');
};

get '/login' => sub {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->redirect_to(User::getLoginLink);
};
```

I use Morbo in development. I don't need to restart Morbo if I change code in this 2 subs, but User::getLoginLink will be updated only with morbo's restart. Is it possible to make morbo watch for changes in modules? (for example, 'User' module)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use option **-w** of **morbo** server. By default **morbo** watch for changes only application script and catalogs **lib** and **templates** in current directory.

Example of usage from **morbo** help:

```
morbo -w /usr/local/lib -w public myapp.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

Run morbo under the perl debugger (perl -d /path/to/morbo /path/to/script) and diagnose where it is hanging.

You also might look at the built-in Morbo debugging. Enable the environment variables MOJO_DAEMON_DEBUG and MOJO_BASE_DEBUG for more info from Morbo/Hypnotoad. See [the Mojolicious Wiki ENV list](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/%25ENV_list) for more debugging options.